# Column value should be unique to another column value

Tags: sql, csv, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I'm creating an SSIS package wherein a user needs to be notified if there is a  duplicate productid for one productname. We retrieve the products thru a csv file being sent to us in a shared location.

In this example I have ProductID = 1 for both products chair and lamp.

So basically the productID = 1 was a duplicate because it was also used by the product lamp. Hence, notify users for the duplicate ProductIDs used.

Can someone give me tips on how to do this?

[image: Product Info]

Comment: Create a unique index on ProductId.

Comment: Hi @SamM the data are being retrieved from a csv file.

Comment: have you check the link i provided in my answer???

Comment: @Chadwick you have asked  [very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036780/how-to-get-desired-output-in-ssis-by-grouping-by-and-count) and you got an answer, if the issue is solved the you have to accept an answer or write your own.

Comment: @Chadwick i edited my answer and added related links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 3 approaches:

1. Insert data into a staging table and use a query similar to:

   ```
   SELECT PRODUCTID, COUNT(*) 
   FROM TEMPTABLE
   GROUP BY PRODUCTID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ```
2. Use a Script component to count occurrences and throw exception when duplicates found. Check the following link for more information:

   - [How to get desired output in SSIS by grouping by and count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036780/how-to-get-desired-output-in-ssis-by-grouping-by-and-count?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. Use aggregate transformation and apply count with group by on `ProductID`, check the following link fro more information:

   - [SSIS - Perform group by and count on flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696647/ssis-perform-group-by-and-count-on-flat-file)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to get a count of duplicate PRODID values.

Use an `Aggregate` transform using

```
Column PRODID - Operation Group By
Column (*) - Operation Count all
```

Follow it with a `Conditional Split` where `[Count all] > (DT_UI8)1`.

If there are any records in the output, then there was one or more duplicates.

Comment: Hello @lit! Thank you for the response! I already did that  the conditional split where I count all the duplicates I insert it in a destination table with the productid/productcode column and the count column. But another question how can I add the productlabel in the result?

Comment: What is a `productlabel`? Do you mean `ProductName`?

Comment: Hi @lit. Yes productname. :)