# How to get desired output in SSIS by grouping by and count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I'm creating an SSIS package wherein a user needs to be notified if there is a duplicate productcode for one productlabel. We retrieve the products thru a csv flat file being sent to us in a shared location.

In this example I have Productcode = 1a for both productlabel Physio Ormix and Nixen.

So basically the productcode = 1a was a duplicate because it was also used by the productlabel=Nixen. Hence, notify users for the duplicate ProductCode and Productlabel used. I tried creating an aggregate that performs group by ProductCode and Counts it.

[image: In this link is the image of my dataflow]

Can someone give me tips on how to do this?

[image: In this link is the desired output]

Comment: It looks like your conditional split could be the place to send the duplicates off to an email task. You want to split on records with a count > 1 in the file.

Comment: Just load the data into a staging (interim) table and run the proper SQL that flags the duplicates from SSIS, capture its findings and process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a script component and a conditional split to get the duplicates without all this logic:

1. Inside the data flow task add a Script Component
2. Add an output column of type `DT_BOOL` (example name is `Flag`)
3. Inside the script component write a similar script:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public class ScriptMain:  
       UserComponent  

   {  

       List<string> lstKey = new List<string>;
       List<string> lstKeylabel = new List<string>;

       public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(InputBuffer0 Row)  
       {  

           if(!lstKey.Contains(Row.ProductCode){

               lstKey.Add(Row.ProductCode);
               lstKeylabel.Add(Row.ProductCode + ";" + Row.ProductLabel);
               Row.Flag = true;

           }else if(lstKeylabel.Contains(Row.ProductCode + ";" + Row.ProductLabel)) {

               Row.Flag = true;

           }else{

               Row.Flag = false;

           }

       }  

   }
   ```
4. Add a conditional split after the script component with a similar expression:

   ```
   [Flag] == true
   ```
5. All records that are passed thru the *true path* are unique, all rows passed in the *false path* are the duplicates.

Comment: Hello @Hadi! Thank you so much for your response! I tried this but this has the same output with what I did earlier it got the duplicate 1a Physio Ormix instead of getting the duplicate productcode which was used by another productlabel -  1A nixen

Comment: @Chadwick this approach will split the flow into unique values and duplicate. why it is not working?

Comment: Hello @Hadi! Yes sir it did separate the unique values and the duplicate. But in this scenario it doesn't mind having 5 rows with the same values for 1A Physio Ormix. As long as it is using the same productcode for one product label only. So the problem here is,  I need to retrieve the record that is using the the same productcode but having a different productlabel like 1A Nixen.

Comment: @Chadwick it can be solved by adding another list. Check the updated script

Comment: sir @Hadi! What the heck! it worked like magic! Thank you so much for your help!